# Intel DH57JG vs. Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, installation, intel-graphics

I've installed 11.04 on my pc (processor i5 660) and what I get on start-up is in sequence a violet screen a black one and after system crash.
The unique way to log in Ubuntu is in recovery mode. I made test for unity 3d, it failed so I installed unity-2d but nothing changed.

Launching `less  /var/log/Xorg.0.log` I noted this two warnings:

```
(WW) Falling back to old probe method for vesa

(WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
```

Can please someone help me to resolve this problem and win fighting against Ubuntu?

I've read on a forum that a solution is to downgrade kernel to a previous working version but it was not explained and I do not know how to do it :-(

My Ubuntu version is i386; can resolve my problem AMD64 version?

Thanks in advance

ciao h.

Answer (score 1):

All my problem are probably due to motherboard fault here a post in [Intel community](http://communities.intel.com/message/108902#108902) that explain problem in details, unique solution is to send back to reseller to get a working one.

thanks again

ciao

h

Comment: I've spoken of this problem in other 2 post can you close and link in some way to this? thanks in advance, follow links: http://askubuntu.com/questions/41699/problem-with-grub http://askubuntu.com/questions/41094/help-needed-to-correct-xorg-warning